# CSS3 Transitions On ios Slow/Not Working

Tags: ios, css, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to start using some CSS3 transitions on responsive site I'm making and everything is working perfectly on desktop Chrome, and Chrome on Android but it's not working properly on ios devices for both Chrome and Safari.

The CSS snippet I'm using for my menu, for instance, is below:

```
#menu {
width: 180px;
height: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
left: -180px; 
z-index: 9; 
transition: left 1s; 
-webkit-transition: left 1s;
}
```

I have a menu button that, when clicked, calls a javascript function that changes the 'left' style to 0 which has it transition into position from outside of the left side of the screen.

Everything works fine on desktop and Chrome Android but on ios Chrome and Safari it is either very choppy or it just delays a second and then pops up instantly. It's doing this on all of my transitions but I'm showing the menu one for simplicity.

I have done a LOT of googling and searching through Stack but the only things I've really found say to add the following:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

to the style to force hardware acceleration but it's not working either. I see no change at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Avoid using absolute positioning transitions it takes lot of resources, instead try using `transform: translateX(0) ` for horizontal adjustment

Comment: @Swordys I'll give that a check. I haven't really messed with 'transform' before because I haven't really been trying transitions until recently, especially not for mobile. I'm also having the same problem with the choppyness/not working on elements that don't change positioning but have the transition on the max-height and opacity. Is it best to just use transform for all of them?

Comment: Yes, if you're using lot of transitions on absolute elements it will have large impact on performance. Using transitions is the best practice for smooth experience. You can also try using `will-change: transform` to force hardware acceleration but currently it's not supported on safari browser.

Comment: @Swordys Changing to `transform: translateX(0)` method helped immensely. The menu is now completely smooth. If you'd like to make this an actual answer to the question that would be great so I can mark it as the correct answer and give you credit for it. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, glad i could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using absolute positioning transitions it takes lot of resources, instead try using `transform: translateX(0)` for horizontal adjustment

Comment: This worked perfectly for the menu. Any advice on how to get `transition: max-height 1s, opacity 1s` to not be choppy/just pop up? I can't seem to find a transform for opacity or max-height.

Comment: Did you tried using any transition timing functions like `ease-out` or `ease` after seconds indicator?

Comment: I have tried using `ease-in-out` , `ease` and `linear` and it's the same thing. I just did a quick test and it's the transition on the `max-height` that's having the issue. The `opacity` transitions smoothly but when I try to transition the `max-height` it is what is jumpy. What I'm doing with this is kind of the workaround for transitioning to `height: auto;` since that doesn't work.

Comment: Height transitions are costly as-well, best bet would be to give that element fixed height and just use `transform: translateY()` for vertical pop up effect just like previous example. Also set it's parent element `oveflow: hidden` so it can hide behind it.

Comment: That makes sense. If you have a few minutes if you could check out this jsfiddle I just quickly made to show what I'm trying to accomplish with the max-height thing. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/301kmxch/1/) I am having these 'options divs' appear just under whatever button/link opens them and they all have different heights, etc. I'm not sure how I could get the `translateY` to work where it would still appear in the correct spot without showing a huge gap between the two buttons if that makes sense.