# CSS Transition Auto Height Without Slowness On Mobile

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I had posted a question earlier in regards to CSS transitions being slow on ios/mobile browsers and received an answer for my 'menu' I had working. You can find that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196935/css3-transitions-on-ios-slow-not-working/40197212).

Now I'm trying to fix the rest of my transitions. I have a form I am trying to make dynamic in terms of 'if yes to this then answer these new questions that pop up just below'. The problem I'm having is the transition for `max-height` is super slow/nonexistant on ios Safari and Chrome.

You can see the code below using [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/301kmxch/1/). I'd like to have the 'options' pop up below the buttons without showing any whitespace between the buttons. When using `translateY` instead of the `max-height` option there would be whitespace between the two buttons in the height that the hiddendiv is.

The 'options' divs would be different heights because the number of questions would be different for each of these dynamic inputs.

Here is a quick example of the code I'm using:

```
<input type='button' onclick="toggleoptions('options1')" value="Show Options">
<div id="options1" class="hiddendiv">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
</div><input type='button' onclick="toggleoptions('options2')" value="Show Options">
<div id="options2" class="hiddendiv">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Option here..."><br>
</div>
And more stuff goes here....

<script>
function toggleoptions(forthisdiv) {
var optionsdiv = document.getElementById(forthisdiv);
if(optionsdiv.style.opacity == 0) {
  optionsdiv.style.maxHeight = "1000px";
  optionsdiv.style.opacity = 1;
 }
 else {
  optionsdiv.style.maxHeight = 0;
  optionsdiv.style.opacity = 0;
  }
}
</script>
```

And the CSS:

```
.hiddendiv {
overflow: hidden; 
max-height: 0;
opacity: 0; 
transition: all 1s;
}
```